# UITextField PlaceHolder Color change Monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, placeholder

I have been trying to change the color of `UItextfield` placeholder and I have had no luck. I have tried sub classing, and I have tried modifying the Attributed string but nothing worked.

This is the subclass I tried.

```
public class CustomTextbox : UITextField
{
    private string placeholder{ get;  set; }
    public CustomTextbox ()
    {
    }

    public CustomTextbox(string theString)
    {
        this.placeholder = theString;
    }

    public override void DrawPlaceholder (RectangleF rect) {
        using (UIFont font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (16)) 
        using (UIColor col = new UIColor (UIColor.Blue.CGColor)) { 
            col.SetFill (); col.SetStroke (); col.SetColor (); base.DrawString (base.Placeholder,rect, font); } }
            

}
```

This is the attributed string method I tried:

```
var textat = new NSMutableAttributedString ("Email", new CTStringAttributes () {

            
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.White.CGColor,StrokeColor = UIColor.White.CGColor,
            StrokeWidth = 5.0f
        });
        this.emailtextbox.AttributedPlaceholder = textat;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just simplify what you already have.
This works on iOS7:

```
var t = new UITextField()
{
  AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString("some placeholder text", null, UIColor.Red)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much . This helped me. i forgot that NSAttributedString had all its parameters set only really needed the first 3 and could leave the rest to be set to null. Thanks again

Comment: Same problem and same solution do not know why, but fixed it!

Comment: What if you only want to change the _color_ of the placeholder and not create a string for the _text_? Is there a way to use the same NSAttributedString object but just nullify the first argument?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do that. If there is _no text_, why would you want to set its color?

Comment: My placeholder text is already set? And I need to change its color at some point without writing extra code I don't need, ie. the same string?

Comment: Well, read the current placeholder value, create an `NSAttributedString` from it with your color and set it back.

Comment: That totally works and I have no idea why I didn't try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The monotuch way to do this is (the answer is found [here](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=pxamarin%20ios%20placeholder%20color&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=-q-xVpO9BIa40gS6nKTQDQ#q=xamarin%20ios%20uitextfield%20placeholder%20text%20color))

```
myLogin.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString (
    "Enter your credentials",
    font: UIFont.FromName ("HoeflerText-Regular", 24.0f),
    foregroundColor: UIColor.Red,
    strokeWidth: 4 
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
[yourtextField setValue:[UIColor blueColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Comment: This is ObjC. And even though it can probably be translated easily into C#, it would be worth mentioning that fact.